# Hide elements with CSS only

Tags: html, css

In the following markup without changing it or using JS, implement the behavior to show only the `ul` element of `div` which name is clicked in the first `ul` (before `div`). Name is content of `li` in top `ul` and it matches the content of the first `li` in `ul` you want to show. Elements that have `{content}` are just fillers and have no meaning for problem.

```css
div > ul:target{
  display: block;
}

div > ul{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="head"><a href="#favorites">Favourites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#breakfasts"><i>Breakfasts</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#dinners"><i>Dinners</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#suppers"><i>Suppers</i></a></li>
</ul>
<div>
  <ul id="breakfasts">
    <li class="head">Breakfasts</li>
    <li>{Breakfast 1}</li>
    <li>{Breakfast 2}</li>
    <li>{Breakfast 3}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="dinners">
    <li class="head">Dinners</li>
    <li>{Dinner 1}</li>
    <li>{Dinner 2}</li>
    <li>{Dinner 3}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="suppers">
    <li class="head">Dinners</li>
    <li>{Supper 1}</li>
    <li>{Supper 2}</li>
    <li>{Supper 3}</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="favorites">
    <li class="head">Favourites</li>
    <li>{Favourite 1}</li>
    <li>{Favourite 2}</li>
    <li>{Favourite 3}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This problem really has the solution and was very interesting for me, so I decided to post it here even if it's not very practical.

The following implementation solves almost solves the problem, but it's not showing the "Favourites" element if first `li` is clicked. So, is there a way to add this functional with CSS only?

Comment: Could your issue be that you are using a class of `favorites` instead of an ID like all of the others?

Comment: @RobertC thanks, but the idea of the problem is not to change anything in html, so class is important

Comment: use my updated answer

Comment: @Mojtaba thanks, but it's not an option too, the trick is not to change html

Comment: Not possible to do this without the ID

Comment: It's possible. Only if you change the HTML, or add JavaScript code. I updated my answer

Comment: `:target` only works if you use an ID.  If your goal is to rely on `:target` then you have to address the discrepancy of your Favorites list being a class instead of an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it only with CSS. Because you need an **id** for that element.

change this:

```
<ul class="favorites">
```

to this:

```
<ul id="favorites" class="favorites">
```

```css
div > ul:target{
   display: block;
}

div > ul{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="head"><a href="#favorites">Favourites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#breakfasts"><i>Breakfasts</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#dinners"><i>Dinners</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#suppers"><i>Suppers</i></a></li>
</ul>
<div>
    <ul id="breakfasts">
       <li class="head">Breakfasts</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 1}</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 2}</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="dinners">
       <li class="head">Dinners</li>
       <li>{Dinner 1}</li>
       <li>{Dinner 2}</li>
       <li>{Dinner 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="suppers">
       <li class="head">Dinners</li>
       <li>{Supper 1}</li>
       <li>{Supper 2}</li>
       <li>{Supper 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="favorites" class="favorites">
       <li class="head">Favourites</li>
       <li>{Favourite 1}</li>
       <li>{Favourite 2}</li>
       <li>{Favourite 3}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**But**, if you have to keep the current HTML format, you need to add the **id** by JavaScript:

```js
var favs = document.getElementsByClassName("favorites");
favs[0].setAttribute('id', 'favorites');
```

```css
div > ul:target{
   display: block;
}

div > ul{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="head"><a href="#favorites">Favourites</a></li>
  <li><a href="#breakfasts"><i>Breakfasts</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#dinners"><i>Dinners</i></a></li>
  <li><a href="#suppers"><i>Suppers</i></a></li>
</ul>
<div>
    <ul id="breakfasts">
       <li class="head">Breakfasts</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 1}</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 2}</li>
       <li>{Breakfast 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="dinners">
       <li class="head">Dinners</li>
       <li>{Dinner 1}</li>
       <li>{Dinner 2}</li>
       <li>{Dinner 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="suppers">
       <li class="head">Dinners</li>
       <li>{Supper 1}</li>
       <li>{Supper 2}</li>
       <li>{Supper 3}</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="favorites">
       <li class="head">Favourites</li>
       <li>{Favourite 1}</li>
       <li>{Favourite 2}</li>
       <li>{Favourite 3}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: OP says he doesn't want to change the HTML or rely on JavaScript.  In essence, he doesn't want a solution.

Comment: @RobertC, agree. I showed up the possible ways. s/he can use one of them or wait forever. We know there's no way to do that without manipulating directly or indirectly the id

Comment: thank you for really good proposals, I think, I'll mark your answer as accepted, and when I'll figure out the CSS only way, I'll post it as an answer

Comment: and sorry for such a weird question, actually, the other person asked me that and he really claims to have CSS-only solution

Comment: @snowfinch27, trust us. Don't waste your time. there is no way to do by css only. When you are linking to a DOM element by #, for sure, you need **id**. CSS can't add attributes to the elements